# SQL Syntax Error Code 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysql-error-1064

My code is here;

```
$m = 0.5;

$this->db->query("update chatusers set money = money - ".$m." where user = '".$this->input->post('member')."'");
```

and I'm getting this error;

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where user = ''' at line 1
>
> update chatusers set money = money - where user = ''
>
> Filename: /home/modenatu/public_html/beta/models/model/mupdate.php
>
> Line Number: 87

I couldn't find how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done the minimal of troubleshooting? Like echoing out the query?

Comment: Are you posting a field called `'member'`?  What's `$m`?

Comment: P.S. This code is *wide open* to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$m` is evaluating to an empty string, based on the error message.

It looks like `$this->input->post('member')` is also evaluating to an empty string.

```
update chatusers set money = money - where user = ''
                                    ^              ^
```

Because if those two evaluated to non-empty strings (say for example `'foo'` and `'bar'` respectively) we'd expect the SQL to be like this:

```
update chatusers set money = money - foo where user = 'bar'
                                     ^^^               ^^^
```

---

Thankfully, `$m` didn't evaluate to a more nefarious string. Such as **`money WHERE 1=1 --`**

Which would have produced a statement like this:

```
update chatusers set money = money - money WHERE 1=1 -- foo where user = ''
```

The symptom of the problem is invalid syntax. The real problems here are 1) potential for SQL Injection (we don't see what values $m contains), and 2) code is producing invalid SQL statement.

For the sake of everything good and beautiful in this world... I can't emphasize this enough... use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

For example:

```
  $sql = 'UPDATE chatusers SET money = money - ? WHERE user = ?';
  $this->db->query($sql, array(0, 'me'));
```

Comment: @birlikbilisim: Unfortunately, CodeIgniter doesn't support prepared statements. But the example I gave is the pattern you want to use with CodeIgniter... because it gives you a static SQL statement, and you are supplying values (which is very similar to what we do with prepared statements)... the difference here is that under covers CodeIgniter is escaping the values you provide, making the values safe for inclusion in a SQL statement, which closes some SQL Injection vulnerabilities. (So, it's not the same thing as a prepared statement.) My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

`$m` clearly has no value which is causing your query to have an invalid syntax. You need to verify that `$m` has a valid value *before* you attempt to run that query. (FYI, `$this->input->post('member')` also has no value and using this value unsanitized exposes you to SQL injections).

Comment: No, $m has a value. $m = 0.5;

Comment: It clearly does not have one when it reaches your query. Are you sure that variable is in scope?